# Circular app context dependency with React Context

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I have two hooks, `useA` and `useB`, which perform expensive operations (let's assume network API calls) and these values need to be saved into a global application state (`AppContext`) using React's Context API. Furthermore, the behaviour of the second hook, `useB`, depends on the result of the first hook, `useA`.

These hooks are invoked once the application is started and the context provider is created.  I call the hooks in the context provider component, and I consume the same context inside the second hook. This creates a problem which results into stale information; the `useContext(AppContext)` inside `useB` does not provide correct results for `useA`. Because the result of `useA` is needed outside of the context of the `useB` hook, I cannot move its invocation under the `useB` hook. Otherwise, this would result into two calls to `useA`, once inside the context provider and once inside `useB`.

How could this issue be solved?

```js
const useA = () => {
  const api = useApi()
  const [state, setState] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    api.someFn().then((result) => {
      setState(result)
    })
  }, [api])

  return state
}

const useB = () => {
  const api = useApi()
  const { a } = useContext(AppContext)
  const [state, setState] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    api.someOtherFn(a.someVariable).then((result) => {
      setState(result)
    })
  }, [api, a])

  return state
}

const AppContext = createContext({ a: null, b: null })

const AppContextProvider = (children) => {
  const a = useA()
  const b = useB()

  const context = { a, b }

  return <AppContext.Provider value={context}>{children}</AppContext.Provider>
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <AppContextProvider>
      <Router>
        ...
      </Router>
    </AppContextProvider>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following will be useful:

```js
const useA = () => {
  const api = useApi()
  const [state, setState] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    api.someFn().then((result) => {
      setState(result)
    })
  }, [api])

  return state
}

const useB = (a) => {
  const api = useApi()
  const [state, setState] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (a && a.someVariable) {
      api.someOtherFn(a.someVariable).then((result) => {
        setState(result)
      })
    }
  }, [api, a])

  return state
}

const AppContext = createContext({ a: null, b: null })

const AppContextProvider = (children) => {
  const a = useA()
  const b = useB(a)

  // It is not recommended to pack several values into some object and share it via context
  // Cause consumers will be retriggered on each call to AppContextProvider
  const context = { a, b }

  return <AppContext.Provider value={context}>{children}</AppContext.Provider>
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <AppContextProvider>
      <Router>
        ...
      </Router>
    </AppContextProvider>
  )
}
```

Please read about multiple contexts https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#consuming-multiple-contexts